# Is it possible to track visitor that leave or page to another sites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tracking

Is it possible to track visitor that leave or page to another sites,
like ask question only when they want move to another sites or other domain name? I write this code

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "leave?";
  }
</script>
```

But this code work everytime even on my own pages. I want to make this code to run just if visitors go to another domain by tiping URL (Not by links). Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't visit your site again if it had such a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a task for a browser plugin, not a page script. It's not possible for JS to know what the user does outside the page.

If this were possible, that would be a whole new security problem, a privacy issue, and I won't visit your site.

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged jquery in this question I guess you are already  using  http://jquery.com/

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a").click(function(){
       if( fnGetDomain(document.location) == fnGetDomain($(this).attr("href")) )
       {
            return true;
       }
       else{
            return confirm("Leave page?");
       }

   });
});
function fnGetDomain(url) {
  return url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
}
</script>
```

You can use `document.location.href` in place of `document.location` if there is any problem

Comment: No, i mean visits using direct URL not using links. But thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a thing here, not sure it works on every cases...

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

function confirmExit(event)
{
    console.log(event);
    console.log("Current : " + event.srcElement.domain);
    console.log("Target : " + event.target.domain);
    if (event.srcElement.domain != event.target.domain)
    {
        return "leave ?";
    }
    else
    {
        // staying here
    }
}​
```