# Accounting for users that have left website without using onunload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, cookies, design-patterns

I have a webservice with very limited resources (I will be able to handle about 3 simultaneous users).

When users interact with my website they start a complex process server-side. (This process is the limiting factor, as my server machine will not be able to handle many in parallel, and clients cannot run this on their side.)

My question is how to make sure to end the process for users that leave, for example by closing the window.

I have considered **onunload** and **onbeforeunload**, but they are also triggered by links within the website (which I need for users to be able to interact with the process) so that does not seem like an option.

This approach seems problematic according to other questions ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563284/is-it-possible-to-track-visitor-that-leave-or-page-to-another-sites), for example), but it could work if there were a way to check if the user is still an active user when performing the action triggered by onunload (even if in a different page of the website), but I don't know how to do this.

I have also considered periodically checking the list of active users and cancelling the process for users that have left, but I don't know if this is even possible.

I have zero experience with cookies, but could this be a place to use them? Can the server access the (still living) cookies of disconnected users?

Which sounds like a reasonable approach for this problem?

Comment: Once the web page has loaded then there is no way to tell if the user has the page open in front of them unless you used WebSockets or some sort of polling. But seeing as how the server is so limited on resources that might not be reasonable. I would focus more energy on making whatever those processes are, more efficient. Like, do those processes have to run on that server, the same one that serves web requests? Maybe the web server is trying to do too much stuff.

Comment: Ideally, you are right. But this is a very particular research project, I am afraid there is little I can do along those lines (short of getting resources I'm not going to get or making a breakthrough that will make me famous in the research world ;) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cases such as these are generally handled by heartbeats. Have your client send periodic heartbeats (which are essentially pings) to the server notifying that it is still alive and interested in the process's results. And the server automatically kills those processes for which it hasn't received client heartbeat for a configured amount of time.

> I have considered onunload and onbeforeunload

You are right- you can't rely on them.

> I have zero experience with cookies, but could this be a place to use them?

No. Cookies maintain client-side state that is sent to a server on HTTP calls. So, servers don't manage cookies. Instead, they only look at them to identify state.

Comment: Yes, this sounds promising. I will look into heartbeats, thanks!

Comment: Sure I will ;) I will just need a bit of time to figure this out, but if I manage to get it working I will absolutely remember to do it.

Comment: I struggled for a bit, but I have heartbeats working now :) Thanks for your contribution!